# Ошибка при работе SharpDX

Tags: sharpdx

Изучаю SharpDX на примерах с https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D11. Но, к сожалению, при компиляции примеров студия выбрасывает исключение неясной природы.

```
// Create Device and SwapChain
Device device;
SwapChain swapChain;
Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, desc, out device, out swapChain);
var context = device.ImmediateContext;

// Ignore all windows events
var factory = swapChain.GetParent<Factory>();
factory.MakeWindowAssociation(form.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

// Compile Vertex and Pixel shaders
var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCube.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0");
var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);

var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCube.fx"...
var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCodet);

var signature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode...
// Layout from VertexShader input signature
var layout = new InputLayout(device, signature, new[]
        {
            new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float,...
            new InputElement("COLOR", _, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 16...
        });
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll
>
> Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode:
>   [E_INVALID/Invalid Arguments], Message: Параметр задан неверно.

Пробовал разные версии SharpDX.
Очень нужна помощь!
Windows 8.1, DirectX11,VS2013CE

Comment: Пришел домой...та же win8.1,  та же студия, тот же с*ка распакованный архив sharpdx -- работает. Was ist das? Was ist los?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была успешно решена. Ответ скрывался в том, что рабочая видеокарта GeForce 7100 в отличие от домашней GeForce 9500 не поддерживает directX11 с его шейдерной моделью 4.0-5.0... карточка GeForce 7100 поддерживает только direct9.0c с шейдерной моделью 3.0.